# MySQL time math

Tags: mysql, datetime, math, time, insert

I want to insert a row into a MySQL table, and one of the values should be the time now (of the MySQL server) plus 5 seconds.

I see a NOW() function that MySQL recognizes, but can I add seconds to that value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 5 SECOND
```

Also possible:

```
SELECT date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)
```

See [here for the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Hope this helps.